# sitecore webform marketers: the use of formsRoot

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7

According to the [Web forms for marketers 2.3 reference guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_3%20reference-a4.pdf), I can set formsRoot parameter in my site definition. And this is my config for the site.

```
<site name="example" 
        hostName="www.helloCommerce.com" 
        virtualFolder="/" 
        physicalFolder="/" 
        content="master" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/E-Commerce Examples" 
        startItem="/home" 
        database="web" 
        domain="extranet" 
        allowDebug="true" 
        cacheHtml="false" 
        htmlCacheSize="10MB" 
        EcommerceSiteSettings="/Site Settings" 
        browserTitle="Example" 
        registryCacheSize="0" 
        viewStateCacheSize="0" 
        xslCacheSize="5MB" 
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
        enablePreview="true" 
        enableWebEdit="true" 
        enableDebugger="true" 
        disableClientData="false" 
        ordersDatabase="orders" 
        actionLogDatabase="logging" 
        patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        formsRoot="/sitecore/System/modules/Web Forms for Marketers/local forms"/>
```

And I will go through the process of creating the web form by:
All Applications/Web Forms for Marketers/Create a New form
after I have filled in all the fields, and in the last step (confirmation), the form always will be created in /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Sample forms/Example Form but not in 'local forms' folder.

Did I miss out any step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like :

```xml
<sites>
  <site name="website">
    <patch:arttribute name="formsRoot">{4F42E032-6174-4A79-B3B0-5056494D6B39}</patch:arttribute>
  </site>
</sites>
```

and it works fine for me, please check if is working . On your case just modify path of item with item ID.